# Reduce flickering in vlc

Tags: objective-c, ios7

i am doing vlc integration in my Xcodeproject(Objective c). I used MobileVlcKit.framework version 2.2.0-git Weatherwax.
It can be seems that some flickering during play.

How to avoid flickering in vlc??  Can you suggest any parameter that can be changed in order to reduce flickering??